# How to click a button on a website by finding its id

Tags: python, html, selenium

When I run the code, the website loads up fine but then it won't click on the button- an error appears saying the element is not interacterble. What do I need to do to click the button? I am relatively new to this and would be grateful for any help.

I have already tried finding it by id and tag.

```
page = driver.get("https://kenpreston.co.uk/author/")
element = driver.find_element_by_id('mk-button-31')
element.click()
```

SOLVED:
I used `driver.find_element_by_link_text` and this worked fine.

Comment: you should target the href... something like this: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href="'free-joe-coffin-book-offer")]')

Comment: You can wait for the element to be clickable.

Comment: And the button is visible as??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the website and noticed that `mk-button-31` is an id for a `div` tag and inside it there is an `a` tag. Try getting the url from the `a` tag and do another `driver.get` instead of clicking on it.

Also the whole div tag is not clickable so that is why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use sleep from time library to be sure page fully loaded

```
from time import sleep
page = driver.get("https://kenpreston.co.uk/author/")
sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('mk-button-31')
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your element is not clickable you need to replace this `id` selector with the `css` and need to wait for the element before click on it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

page = driver.get("https://kenpreston.co.uk/author/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mk-button-31 span"))
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to your script as it might be the case the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) had finished loading and the button you're looking for is still not there.

The classes you're looking for are:

- [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait)
- [expected_conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

Suggested code change:

```
#your other imports here
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
#your other code here
page = driver.get("https://kenpreston.co.uk/author/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mk-button-31")))
element.click()
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)